# Spring RMI Server Error

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, rmi

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service [logService] is a String rather than an actual service reference: Have you accidentally specified the service bean name as value instead of as reference?
```

---

Here is my code for ServerAppContext:

```
    <bean id="entityRmiServiceExporter" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
        <property name="serviceName" value="log-service"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.hippie.blog.service.LogService"/>
        <property name="service" value="logService"/>
        <property name="registryPort" value="2020"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logService" class="com.hippie.blog.service.LogServiceImpl">
    </bean>
```

I can't seem to make it work. What do I suppose to put in

> property name="service" value="logService"

because that is the line that the error is referring to.
Do I need to refer it to my `LogServiceImpl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as below:
`<property name="service" ref="logService"/>`
when you refer to other bean then use ref attribute, not value.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks mate. Silly I was looking at this tutorial http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/remoting.html and I notice the value and ref.